# If $\{w^k|w\in L\}$ regular implies L regular?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

If L is a language and the language 
$$\tilde{L}:=\{x^k,x\in L, k\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
is regular, does that imply that L is regular? ($|L|<\infty$ gives equivalence)

We came across this question when trying to prove an explicit example, namely

> Prove that $L=\{a^{p^k}\mid p\text{ prime}, k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular.

It was fairly easy to show that $L_1=\{\underbrace{a^{p^1}}_{=a^p}\mid p\text{ prime}\}$
is not regular. If the above statement were true, this would give a very easy proof for the assignment.

I am asking out of interest, there are other ways to solve the question (I am NOT asking for answers on this example). I tried proving it via the pumping lemma, explicit construction of a FSA and the Myhill-Nerode theorem, however I was unable to find any notable results. I am unsure if this statement is true or if we can find a counterexample (I have been unable to do so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $L = \{a^{n^2} \colon n \ge 1\}$. As $a \in L$, your $\tilde{L} = \mathcal{L}(a^*)$, which is regular, but $L$ isn't.

Comment: I could have thought of that. Under which conditions is the statement true however? Can such a broad statement be given?

Comment: It is ulikely that there is a "simple" case where this works, consider [Parikh's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem) (that is for CFG, but also valid for regular languages) by interleaving $k$ times the "shortest" strings in $L$ you end up filling in the gaps. I'd venture that your $\tilde{L}$'s will end up complying to the pumping lemma whatever $L$ might be.

Answer (score 0):

Take *any* nonregular language $L$ of $a^*$ containing $a$. Then $\tilde L = a^*$ is always regular. This gives little hope for your problem.